# Parse 2 files line by line, search and replace in a 3rd file

Tags: bash, sed, replace

I'm trying to make a bash script which does the following :

- parses 2 files which have the same number of lines
- searches the content of each line of the 2nd file in the 3rd file and in case of match it will replace that content in the 3rd file with the content of the corresponding line of the 1st file.

To be more specific lets say files content looks like this :

file1:

```
10_100test-NFV
APP_SP1 
APP_SP1 
APP_SP1 
ADmanage 
ADmanage 
ADmanage 
ADmanage 
ADmanage 
AFG 
AFG 
Alton-VNET-NFV
Alton-VNET-NFV
Apex-VNet-NFV 
Apex-VNet-NFV
```

file2:

```
4337c0148f79496c8bec580af6adaee1
c9d18ece507f4ac387341890a629215b
039b785080414ef3bad80def7153e56e
a5c2f415b26946eb90d927fb257fb571
466e9135208d44029843d7905bb95bf1
79a9913f25b548a3803511909d49439b
8444da0b23e14b158904433ced89889c
54d6ba8e30e947e3926e59cf813a6cc6
a5911c24f1244577930ed4fe50151ba2
13c812c9fbb748bab62598d26e8fa992
22273e68097f4323a000ca52b2e5b3e5
f4811f2a3b1f41d09925f9048fa2135f
bc58674277ac47ed84b68570ca79aa27
b2b0bf7ae4f5464690e0b753e78ad668
7eabb4119a4d4189b8f6e32d62aa998f
```

file3:

```
00:10:01    DISK_884820fb00f946d9b36efb6dc6d00469     49.81     88.71    286.16      7.53      0.32      6.28      0.84      4.20
00:10:01    DISK_5c5a9e193b434d729873a1c96f14deff      0.65      5.20      0.00      8.00      0.00      5.27      3.41      0.22
00:10:01    DISK_db630dac761946419a174a7958d301d7     13.40     25.14     75.28      7.50      0.07      5.48      1.13      1.51
00:10:01    DISK_79a9913f25b548a3803511909d49439b      8.23      1.55     60.34      7.52      0.04      4.28      0.87      0.72
00:10:01    DISK_892f7dde836641fd84fdb790090ac40c      0.52      3.07      0.65      7.21      0.00      2.97      2.15      0.11
00:10:01    DISK_f8b9c9555f894fdc9c6526f07124d83b     82.56     70.87    573.69      7.81      0.55      6.58      0.65      5.34
00:10:01    DISK_f6b732c30176435e8bc1ed41d58bd6c8    106.63      4.69    507.36      4.80      0.54      5.02      2.00     21.37
00:10:01    DISK_c3f1181557d247e8811765e840705c16      0.19      1.49      0.00      8.00      0.00      4.08      2.29      0.04
00:10:01    DISK_bc00e5020df84ef5aae14c69aec2904c     11.64      1.49     85.53      7.47      0.04      3.57      0.69      0.80
00:10:01    DISK_85e21bfec61c498bbab3d8cbc925d5ca      8.08      3.25     54.15      7.11      0.32     39.87      1.06      0.86
00:10:01    DISK_efb1e9bc83304ed3aee855a4ac7747b1      0.28      1.51      0.46      7.05      0.00      3.67      2.10      0.06
00:10:01    DISK_eb2ff849ddf5439e95ca5df2820e525d      6.60      1.56     27.56      4.41      0.03      4.22      3.43      2.27
```

After running the script the file3 should be something like this :

```
00:10:01    DISK_AFG     49.81     88.71    286.16      7.53      0.32      6.28      0.84      4.20
00:10:01    DISK_Alton-VNET-NFV      0.65      5.20      0.00      8.00      0.00      5.27      3.41      0.22
00:10:01    DISK_ADmanage     13.40     25.14     75.28      7.50      0.07      5.48      1.13      1.51
00:10:01    DISK_79a9913f25b548a3803511909d49439b      8.23      1.55     60.34      7.52      0.04      4.28      0.87      0.72
00:10:01    DISK_10_100test-NFV       0.52      3.07      0.65      7.21      0.00      2.97      2.15      0.11
00:10:01    DISK_AFG     82.56     70.87    573.69      7.81      0.55      6.58      0.65      5.34
00:10:01    DISK_f6b732c30176435e8bc1ed41d58bd6c8    106.63      4.69    507.36      4.80      0.54      5.02      2.00     21.37
00:10:01    DISK_c3f1181557d247e8811765e840705c16      0.19      1.49      0.00      8.00      0.00      4.08      2.29      0.04
00:10:01    DISK_ADmanage     11.64      1.49     85.53      7.47      0.04      3.57      0.69      0.80
00:10:01    DISK_85e21bfec61c498bbab3d8cbc925d5ca      8.08      3.25     54.15      7.11      0.32     39.87      1.06      0.86
00:10:01    DISK_efb1e9bc83304ed3aee855a4ac7747b1      0.28      1.51      0.46      7.05      0.00      3.67      2.10      0.06
00:10:01    DISK_Apex-VNet-NFV      6.60      1.56     27.56      4.41      0.03      4.22      3.43      2.27
```

So far I wrote this but it does not do anything :

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Please enter the path to the first file: " uuids 
read -p "Please enter the path to the second file: " vms
read -p "Please enter the path to the 3rd file: " sar

while read -r vm; do
     while read -r uuid; do 
          grep -o -h -m 1 "$uuid" $sar
          if [ $? -eq 0 ]  
          then
              sed -i "s/$uuid/$vm/g" $sar
              break
          else
              break
          fi
     done < "$uuids"
done < "$vms"
```

Comment: please update the question so that the sample inputs match the desired output; as currently written many of the changes you've made in the desired output ... they don't match with anything in your sample input ... this can lead to confusion since any code we may come up with won't be able to generate the desired output based on the given sample inputs; also, can you update the question with an indication of the size of these files (for each file: number of lines and total MBytes) as this could affect any proposed code (eg, can everything fit into memory or not)

Comment: Thanks @markp-fuso, you are right. The size of the file 1 and 2 is around 40-80kb, 2566 lines and the file 3 is around 3-4MB, 25-30000 lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified copy of `file2` to allow for matching some of the lines in the `file3` sample:

```
$ cat file2
884820fb00f946d9b36efb6dc6d00469
c9d18ece507f4ac387341890a629215b
db630dac761946419a174a7958d301d7
a5c2f415b26946eb90d927fb257fb571
892f7dde836641fd84fdb790090ac40c
79a9913f25b548a3803511909d49439b
f6b732c30176435e8bc1ed41d58bd6c8
54d6ba8e30e947e3926e59cf813a6cc6
c3f1181557d247e8811765e840705c16
13c812c9fbb748bab62598d26e8fa992
85e21bfec61c498bbab3d8cbc925d5ca
f4811f2a3b1f41d09925f9048fa2135f
eb2ff849ddf5439e95ca5df2820e525d
b2b0bf7ae4f5464690e0b753e78ad668
7eabb4119a4d4189b8f6e32d62aa998f
```

One idea using `paste` and `awk` to auto-generate some `sed` commands:

```
$ awk '{printf "s/%s/%s/\n", $1, $2}' < <(paste file2 file1) > list_of_sed_cmds
$ cat list_of_sed_cmnds
s/884820fb00f946d9b36efb6dc6d00469/10_100test-NFV/
s/c9d18ece507f4ac387341890a629215b/APP_SP1/
s/db630dac761946419a174a7958d301d7/APP_SP1/
s/a5c2f415b26946eb90d927fb257fb571/APP_SP1/
s/892f7dde836641fd84fdb790090ac40c/ADmanage/
s/79a9913f25b548a3803511909d49439b/ADmanage/
s/f6b732c30176435e8bc1ed41d58bd6c8/ADmanage/
s/54d6ba8e30e947e3926e59cf813a6cc6/ADmanage/
s/c3f1181557d247e8811765e840705c16/ADmanage/
s/13c812c9fbb748bab62598d26e8fa992/AFG/
s/85e21bfec61c498bbab3d8cbc925d5ca/AFG/
s/f4811f2a3b1f41d09925f9048fa2135f/Alton-VNET-NFV/
s/eb2ff849ddf5439e95ca5df2820e525d/Alton-VNET-NFV/
s/b2b0bf7ae4f5464690e0b753e78ad668/Apex-VNet-NFV/
s/7eabb4119a4d4189b8f6e32d62aa998f/Apex-VNet-NFV/
```

Now apply these `sed` commands against `file3`:

```
$ sed -f list_of_sed_cmnds file3
00:10:01    DISK_10_100test-NFV     49.81     88.71    286.16      7.53      0.32      6.28      0.84      4.20
00:10:01    DISK_5c5a9e193b434d729873a1c96f14deff      0.65      5.20      0.00      8.00      0.00      5.27      3.41      0.22
00:10:01    DISK_APP_SP1     13.40     25.14     75.28      7.50      0.07      5.48      1.13      1.51
00:10:01    DISK_ADmanage      8.23      1.55     60.34      7.52      0.04      4.28      0.87      0.72
00:10:01    DISK_ADmanage      0.52      3.07      0.65      7.21      0.00      2.97      2.15      0.11
00:10:01    DISK_f8b9c9555f894fdc9c6526f07124d83b     82.56     70.87    573.69      7.81      0.55      6.58      0.65      5.34
00:10:01    DISK_ADmanage    106.63      4.69    507.36      4.80      0.54      5.02      2.00     21.37
00:10:01    DISK_ADmanage      0.19      1.49      0.00      8.00      0.00      4.08      2.29      0.04
00:10:01    DISK_bc00e5020df84ef5aae14c69aec2904c     11.64      1.49     85.53      7.47      0.04      3.57      0.69      0.80
00:10:01    DISK_AFG      8.08      3.25     54.15      7.11      0.32     39.87      1.06      0.86
00:10:01    DISK_efb1e9bc83304ed3aee855a4ac7747b1      0.28      1.51      0.46      7.05      0.00      3.67      2.10      0.06
00:10:01    DISK_Alton-VNET-NFV      6.60      1.56     27.56      4.41      0.03      4.22      3.43      2.27
```

Once OP is satisfied the script works as desired the `-i` flag can be added to the `sed -f ....` call to update `file3` with the new modifications.

**NOTE**: As Socowi's stated, this assumes no meta-characters in `file1` or `file2`; if there **are** meta-characters then we would need a more complete set of sample data in order to come up with a workable solution.

Comment: This works @markp-fuso and is very fast. It's more than enough for what I needed in this particular situation. Thanks!

Comment: re: speed ... the `while/while` double loop is going to take a long(er) time if simply because of the large number of times `file3` (aka `$sar`) is being re-read (`grep` and `sed`) and rewritten (`sed`); in this answer we're down to a single read/rewrite of `file3` so the speed difference should be noticeable for any appreciable volume of pattern replacements

Answer (score 0):

> searches the content of each line **of the 2nd file** in the 3rd file

But you searched for lines **from the 1st file** inside the 3rd file:

```
read -p "Please enter the path to the first file: " uuids 
read -p "Please enter the path to the second file: " vms
read -p "Please enter the path to the 3rd file: " sar

# [...] loops and stuff
grep -o -h -m 1 "$uuid" $sar
# [...] loops and stuff
```

You probably wanted to swap `vms` and `uuids`.
Also, instead of the loops I would use this more efficient approach:

```
read -p "Please enter the path to the first file: " vms 
read -p "Please enter the path to the second file: " uuids
read -p "Please enter the path to the 3rd file: " sar

sed -i "$(paste -d/ "$uuids" "$vms" | sed 's|^.*$|s/&/|')" "$sar"
```

Above command only works if the files 1 (`$vms`) and 2 (`$uuids`) do not contain meta characters like `.`, `*`, `\`, or `/`.

Also, file 1 and 2 combined have to be smaller than `ARG_MAX`. For larger files, the `sed` script has to be read from a file:

```
paste -d/ "$uuids" "$vms" | sed 's|^.*$|s/&/|' > sedCommands
sed -i -f sedCommands "$sar"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Socowi, I tried applying your solution but i got an error: 
./sed.sh: line 7: /usr/bin/sed: Argument list too long

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Seems like your actual files were way bigger than those in your example. I added a workaround.

Comment: Tested your workaround and is good. Can you please explain a bit  the sed command sed 's|^.*$|s/&/|'     ?

Comment: Of course. `s|A|B|` replaces `A` with `B`. `^.*$` matches the whole line. `&` is the thing that got replaced. Therefore, `sed 's|^.*$|s/&/|'` prepends `s/` and appends `/` to every line in the input.

Comment: Got it, thanks. So in the sed expression you used `|` instead of `/` so that the `/` could be interpreted as replacing character and not as part of the sed syntax.

Comment: Exactly. `sed 's/^.*$/s\/&\//''` would have worked too, but would be harder to read.